# Field resolver for InputObjectGraphType

Tags: asp.net, graphql, graphql-dotnet

I work on a ASP.NET Web API and have added support for GraphQL requests with [GraphQL for .NET](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet) .
My queries are working as expected but I am now struggling to use the same logic with the mutations.

I have the following logic for my queries:

```
Field<ContactType>("contact", "This field returns the contact by Id",
            arguments: new QueryArguments(QA_ContactId),
            resolve: ctx => ContactResolvers.ContactDetails(ctx));
```

My resolver returns a **ContactDomainEntity** that is then resolved into a **ContactType**:

```
public class ContactType : ObjectGraphType<ContactDomainEntity>
{
    public ContactType()
    {
        Name = "Contact";
        Description = "Contact Type";

        Field(c => c.Id);
        Field(c => c.FirstName, nullable: true);

        Field<ListGraphType<AddressType>, IEnumerable<AddressDTO>>(Field_Addresses)
            .Description("Contact's addresses")
            .Resolve(ctx => LocationResolvers.ResolveAddresses(ctx));
    }
}
```

It all works really well and the address list is resolved with its own reslver (LocationResolvers.ResolveAddresses) which makes it reusable and helps with the separation of concerns.

Now I want to be able to edit a contact and was hoping to use the same logic where child-objects (like the list of addresses) would be handled by their own resolver. So I have created the following mutation:

```
Field<ContactType>("UpdateContact", "This field updates the Contact's details",
                arguments: new QueryArguments(QA_Input<Types.Input.ContactInputType>()),
                resolve: ctx => ContactResolvers.UpdateContact(ctx));
```

with the **ContactInputType**:

```
public class ContactInputType : InputObjectGraphType<ContactInputDTO>
{
    public ContactInputType()
    {
        Name = "UpdateContactInput";
        Description = "Update an existing contact";

        Field(c => c.Id);
        Field(c => c.FirstName, nullable: true);

        Field<ListGraphType<AddressInputType>, IEnumerable<AddressDTO>>("Addresses")
             .Description("Manage contact's addresses")
             .Resolve(ctx => LocationResolvers.ManageAddresses(ctx));
    }
}
```

(Note that I use DTOs to map the fields into an object which makes sense in my case but that **is not related** to my problem)

My issue is that only the resolver 'ContactResolvers.UpdateContact' gets called. The field resolver 'LocationResolvers.ManageAddresses' is never hit. If I replace the addresses field with the following:

```
Field(c => c.Addresses, nullable: true, type: typeof(ListGraphType<AddressInputType>));
```

my `ContactInputDTO` is correctly populated (i.e. its property 'Addresses' contains the right data) but it means I lose control on how the object properties are mapped and have to rely on them having the same name and cannot add additional logic that my resolver might have.

---

**tl;dr** How to use a field resolver with `InputObjectGraphType`? It works fine when returning an `ObjectGraphType` but I can't get it working on the receiving end.